# Python lxml web scraping

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, lxml

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://projecteuler.net/problem=1')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
text=tree.xpath('//div[@class="problem_content"]/text()')
print (text)
```

I have this code and as a result I want to get the text that is a description of the problem, in this case:

> "If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3
>   or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000."

But instead, I am receiving:

```
['\r\n', '\n', '\n']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that text itself is contained in `<p>` slots, so xpath line should be like

```
text=tree.xpath('//div[@role="problem"]/p/text()')
```